# How to create a new .git-project in Gerrit UI as a subdirectory below another directory?

Tags: git, gerrit

I've setup Gerrit and it's now up and running. I have a lot of already existing git-repositories which is imported/connected to Gerrit. But some of the git-repositories are bunched up together in a directory, as sort of sub-directories to that. 
I have, for example, a directory I call "sandbox", and under that I've put .git-projects that is just for learning (Like helloworld.git and stm_discovery_playground.git).

When I do a clone from an already existing repository, one of those that got imported when I did Gerrit Init, i clone with command
git clone ssh://my_username@my_gerrit_host:29418/**sandbox/helloworld.git**
So at first I thought I hade to name new project with the forward slash to get directories with subdirs.
But I can't Create a new project called sandbox/my_new_project. I get the error '400 invalid project name: sandbox/my_new_project'. 
So this was not the way to do it.

How do I create new projects in Gerrit under that directory?
Can I create new container directory for multiple projects?

Comment: Add more info about what are you exactly doing and what is the error message.

Comment: I tried to click Create New Project, enter Project Name "sandbox/my_new_project" and get the error '400 invalid project name: sandbox/my_new_project'. So this was not the way to do it. @MarceloÁviladeOliveira

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your procedure, you can create the "sandbox/my_new_project" using the "Projects > Create New Project" item. The "400 invalid project name" error is not showing what is really happening. Actually you're facing some error in the execution of the git command to create the repository. Probably there's something wrong with your Gerrit installation.

Check:

- The GERRIT_SITE/logs/error_log file
- The GERRIT_SITE directories/files owners and permissions

Comment: You are amazingt! It was the permissions rights that was the issue for me. Now it works perfectly. Thank you!